# Spring app switching to datasource for testing

Tags: spring, web-services, datasource, h2

I haven't found an effective way to do this. I have a spring app that is providing a webservice. This app calls another webservice to get some data. For junit testing purposes I don't want to call the webservice upstream ... instead I want to use an h2 in memory data source. How can I wire my Doa to use the webservice for production but then use the h2 datasource for testing?

I've looked at setting profiles in my context file. This is good for switching to different db datasources but I can't figure out how to define a webservice as a datasource if possible.

Comment: You can use `@MockBean` to replace the service with a mock and use mockito to wire to your database, or the easier, just overwrite the Bean in your test with `@Primary` and your H2 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a DAO/Repository interface with two implementations -- `H2Dao` & `WebServiceDao`. You can annotate them with `@Profile("test")` & `@Profile("production")`, respectively. Then, specify "test" or "production" as the active profile, as appropriate.

Good luck.

Comment: easier than I thought ... answer now seems obvious. Thanks.